# Speed up pyspark parsing large nested json file

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hello I have nested json files with size of 400 megabytes with 200k records.I created a solution using pyspark to parse the file and store in a customized dataframe , but it takes about 5-7 minutes to do this operation which is very slow.

Here is an example of a json file (small one but with same structure as the large ones) :

```
{"status":"success",

 "data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":

[{"metric":{"data0":"T" ,"data1":"O"},"values":[[90,"0"],[80, "0"]]},

{"metric":{"data0":"K" ,"data1":"S"},"values":[[70,"0"],[60, "0"]]},

{"metric":{"data2":"J" ,"data3":"O"},"values":[[50,"0"],[40, "0"]]}]}}
```

Here is the structure of the output dataframe I want :

```
time | value |data0 | data1 | data2  | data3 
90   |   "0" |   "T"|    "O"|   nan  | nan
80   |   "0" |   "T"|    "O"|   nan  | nan
70   |   "0" |   "K"|    "S"|   nan  | nan
60   |   "0" |   "K"|    "S"|   nan  | nan
50   |   "0" |   nan|    nan|   "J"  | "O"
40   |   "0" |   nan|    nan|   "J"  | "O"
```

and this is the pyspark code I used to on the large file to produce the structure of the dataframe listed above:

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
import rapidjson
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from util import schema ,meta_date

new_schema = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(schema))

with open("largefile.json", "r") as json_file:
    result_count = len(rapidjson.load(json_file)["data"]["result"])

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://IP").getOrCreate()


conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '5g'),
                                        ('spark.executor.cores', '4'),
                                        ('spark.driver.memory', '4g'),
                                         ])

spark.sparkContext.stop()
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()


df = spark.read.json("largefile.json")

for data_name in meta_date:
    df = df.withColumn(
        data_name, F.expr(f"transform(data.result, x -> x.metric.{data_name})")
    )

df = (
    df.withColumn("values", F.expr("transform(data.result, x -> x.values)"))
        .withColumn("items", F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in range(0, result_count)]))
        .withColumn("items", F.explode(F.col("items")))
)

for data_name in meta_date:
    df = df.withColumn(data_name, F.col(data_name).getItem(F.col("items")))

df = (df.withColumn("values", F.col("values").getItem(F.col("items")))
      .withColumn("values", F.explode("values"))
      .withColumn("time", F.col("values").getItem(0))
      .withColumn("value", F.col("values").getItem(1))
      .drop("data", "status", "items", "values")).show()
```

My machine has 4 cores (8 logical cores) and memory 16 gb . I'm using the standalone mode with cluster of master and 2 worker nodes.

Any help on how to speed up this process either by editing the cluster configurations or refactoring the transformations in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? Read json, select columns with explode and it looks like match with your desired result.

```
df.select(f.explode('data.result').alias('result')) \
  .select('result.metric.*', f.explode('result.values').alias('values')) \
  .withColumn('time', f.col('values')[0]) \
  .withColumn('value', f.col('values')[1]) \
  .drop('values') \
  .show(truncate=False)

+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|data0|data1|data2|data3|time|value|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
|T    |O    |null |null |90  |0    |
|T    |O    |null |null |80  |0    |
|K    |S    |null |null |70  |0    |
|K    |S    |null |null |60  |0    |
|null |null |J    |O    |50  |0    |
|null |null |J    |O    |40  |0    |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+
```

Comment: I have used the native spark functions only but in your case the logic is not optimised and also read json as a file, count length and create array with this length that will not be parallelized.